# android-sdk-plugin project doesn't know about Android classes

Tags: android, scala, sbt, android-sdk-plugin

I have Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit, Scala `2.11.6` and sbt `0.13.8`.
I have android-sdk installed with at least `android-22`, and `ANDROID_HOME` set properly.

I followed the "Usage" section in [android-sdk-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin) and did the following:

1. Created a fresh directory with the following files:

   - `build.sbt`:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file (".")).
  settings(
    name := "Test",
    version := "0.0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
)
```

- `project/plugins.sbt`:

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "android-sdk-plugin" % "1.4.1")
```

- `project/build.scala`:

```scala
object Build extends android.AutoBuild
```

2. Ran `sbt` and got the following output:

   ```
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
   [info] Loading global plugins from /home/pcn/.sbt/0.13/plugins
   [info] Loading project definition from /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/project
   [info] Updating {file:/home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/project/}test-scala-android-build...
   [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
   [info] Done updating.
   [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
   [info] Set current project to Test (in build file:/home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/)
   >
   ```
3. From `sbt`'s promt, typed `gen-android android-22 com.pcn.android.test Test` and got the following output:

   ```
   [info] Creating project: Test
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
   Error: Project folder '.' is not empty. Please consider using 'android update' instead.
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/java
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/java/com/pcn/android/test
   Added file ./src/main/java/com/pcn/android/test/MainActivity.java
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/androidTest/java
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/androidTest/java/com/pcn/android/test
   Added file ./src/androidTest/java/com/pcn/android/test/MainActivityTest.java
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/res
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/res/values
   Added file ./src/main/res/values/strings.xml
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/res/layout
   Added file ./src/main/res/layout/main.xml
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi
   Added file ./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
   Added file ./build.gradle
   Created directory /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/gradle/wrapper
   [info] Creating SBT project files
   >
   ```
4. From `sbt`'s prompt, typed `compile` and got the following output:

   ```
   [info] Updating {file:/home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/}root...
   [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
   [info] Done updating.
   [info] Compiling 1 Java source to /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/target/scala-2.11/classes...
   [error] /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/java/com/pcn/android/test/MainActivity.java:3: package android.app does not exist
   [error] android.app.Activity
   [error] /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/java/com/pcn/android/test/MainActivity.java:4: package android.os does not exist
   [error] android.os.Bundle
   [error] /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/java/com/pcn/android/test/MainActivity.java:6: cannot find symbol
   [error]   symbol: class Activity
   [error] Activity
   [error] /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/java/com/pcn/android/test/MainActivity.java:10: cannot find symbol
   [error]   symbol:   class Bundle
   [error]   location: class com.pcn.android.test.MainActivity
   [error] Bundle
   [error] /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/java/com/pcn/android/test/MainActivity.java:9: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
   [error] @Override
   [error] /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/java/com/pcn/android/test/MainActivity.java:12: cannot find symbol
   [error]   symbol:   variable super
   [error]   location: class com.pcn.android.test.MainActivity
   [error] super
   [error] /home/pcn/Code/practice/test-scala-android/src/main/java/com/pcn/android/test/MainActivity.java:13: package R does not exist
   [error] R.layout
   [error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
   [error] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 19, 2015 1:18:50 AM
   >
   ```

As we can see, for some reason it doesn't know about `Activity` and other Android classes. What did I do wrong and how do I fix it? I'm a complete noob with sbt so it's great if I can get detailed instructions.

Thanks.

PS: This is the content of my `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`, in case it's relevant:

```scala
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature", "-optimize")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did in build.sbt confused AutoBuild. You can remove the project definition from build.sbt, or remove AutoBuild and apply androidBuild to the project manually.